# UIStepper - start counting from 1

Tags: swift, xcode, uikit, uistepper

I have successfully implemented core data and UISteppers. Every time I try to edit a saved record the UI Stepper starts over from 0. Please help me to figure put what additional code I need to retain the already edited value.

```
    // This function adds the stepper to a field
    //issue: it does not remember the score when i edit it and starts over
    
    @IBAction func counterStepperPressed(_ sender: UIStepper) {
        counterTF.text = Int(sender.value).description
    }
    
    @IBAction func pointStepperPressed(_ sender: UIStepper) {
        pointTF.text = Int(sender.value).description
    }       
    
    @IBAction func savingsStepperPressed(_ sender: UIStepper) {
        savingsTF.text = Int(sender.value).description
    }        
}
```

I have linked core data like so:

```
import CoreData

class AktieViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var counterStepper: UIStepper!
    @IBOutlet weak var pointsStepper: UIStepper!
    @IBOutlet weak var savingsStepper: UIStepper!
    var selectedAktie: Aktie? = nil
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if(selectedAktie != nil) {

            savingsTF.text = selectedAktie?.saving
            counterTF.text = selectedAktie?.counter
            pointTF.text = selectedAktie?.point
        }
    }

    @IBAction func saveAction(_ sender: Any) {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        if(selectedAktie == nil)
        {
            let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Aktie", in: context)

            let newAktie = Aktie (entity: entity!, insertInto: context)
            newAktie.saving = savingsTF.text
            newAktie.point = pointTF.text
            newAktie.counter = counterTF.text
            do {

                try context.save()
                aktieList.append(newAktie)
                navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        }
        catch
        {
          print("context save error")
        }
    }
```

I also have an edit and delete function.

Comment: This isn’t SwiftUI

Comment: All you have in your code are UI components, you need to involve your Core Data entity somehow if you want to persist the values from the steppers.

Comment: you are not setting the value of each stepper in viewDidLoad, only the labels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function eventually solved my question:

```
@IBAction func counterStepperPressed(_ sender: UIStepper) {
    let initialValue=Int(counterTF.text) ?? 0
    let newValue=Int(sender.value)+initialValue
    counterTF.text="\(newValue)"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to add the following code to remember the value in the stepper.

```
if let value=UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "counterStepper") as? Double {
counterStepper.value=value counterTF.text=String(describing: value)
```

And in the action I have added the following code.

```
@IBAction func counterStepperPressed(_ sender: UIStepper) {
    counterTF.text=String(describing: sender.value)
    UserDefaults.standard.setValue(sender.value, forKey: "counterStepper")
    NotificationCenter.default.post(Notification.init(name: Notification.Name("StepperDidChangeValue")))
}
```

The only issue I have is that if I edit a second item it remembers the value of the first item. Somehow it is not remembering the original value of the item.